# How to check for existence of specific date in MySQL 'date' column?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using the code below, I'm having trouble checking whether a specified date exists in a MySQL 'date' column.

```
$data = array(1367971200);

$s=$dbh->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `date`
    FROM
        `report_coa_bal_hist`
    WHERE
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) = ?
");

if ($s->execute($data)) {

    if ($s['date'] == null) {

        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

It's returning false, despite the fact that I can see the date '2013-05-08' displayed in phpMyAdmin.

The table itself contains 70+ entries for that date. It always will do, if it contains any at all, but I just want to know whether it exists or not at this stage.

The date field is a MySQL 'date' type. I'm suspecting that the bug is in my structuring of the PDO calling of the query.

**UPDATE**

Updated `$r['date']` to `$s['date']. I suspect that I still have an issue with the structure of that, but probably need to fix the query so that it gives us results before focusing on this.

Also tried running the query against the database directly and got an empty resultset, despite being able to see that the target date exists. Still baffled!

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly against the database?

Comment: `$r['date']` OR `$s['date']`

Comment: Where `$r['date']` even did come from ?

Comment: Good point @MarkBannister. I just tried that at it said 'empty resultset'. Hmmm...

Comment: @CORRUPT & others, will amend the code. That's definately another issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use a unix timestamp because it contains the seconds. Try using DATE('date')='2013-05-08' in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = array(1367971200);

$s=$dbh->prepare("
SELECT COUNT(`date`) as c_date
FROM
    `report_coa_bal_hist`
WHERE
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) = ?");

if ($s->execute($data)) {
    $result = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result['c_date'] > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking this but just got called away unexpectedly. Will be gone a few hours. Will accept an answer later after further checking (I think this answer might be the one).

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks to everyone who participated. This answer is the one I've used. It's working great. Thanks Yogesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a whole day with UNIX timestamps because of their more accurate nature (i.e. seconds), you would need the textual version:

```
$data = array(date('Y-m-d', 1367971200));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `report_coa_bal_hist`
    WHERE `date` = ?
");

$stmt->execute($data);
$count = current($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));
return $count > 0;
```

Take note of any timezone differences between the server that runs your script and the database server itself.

Answer (score -2):

there are many flaws with your code, not one:

- format of the value you are checking
- way you are checking in SQL
- the way you are getting result

So, the code have to be

```
$data = array('2013-05-07');
$sql  = "SELECT 1 FROM report_coa_bal_hist WHERE `date` = ? LIMIT 1";
$stm  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($data);
return $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Instead of having to pass the date as formatted string, this should also work as query (with timestamp as parameter): `SELECT ... WHERE date = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME( ? )) LIMIT 1`. `DROM_UNIXTIME(...)` converts a timestamp to `datetime`, `DATE()` converts this to `date` (i.e. lowers precision from second to day).

Comment: not "instead" but "as well". there are many ways for date conversions, but it is not the topic of question.